# Telerik MVC DropDownList not binding to model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have the following DropDownList in a Create view.  I populate the list dynamically, cascading from two other lists, and all goes well before posting.  The list populates correctly and I select a suburb.  However, on the model passed into the `Create` action method, `SuburbId` remains null.  What is going on here?

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(model => model.DetailItem.SuburbId)
        .Name("Suburbs")
        .Enable(false)
    )
</div>
```

(`DetailItem` is a property on the view model that holds a reference to the data model.)

Comment: Does this work with a regular Html.DropDownListFor()? Have you tried not setting the name of the DropDownList? It will be inferred from the expression.

Comment: Not setting the name indeed did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @korchev's suggestion above, I removed the Name call, which was actually assigning an explicit name in conflict with the `DetailItem_SuburbId` name generated and assigned by the model binder.